# Reproducing Intellij Idea Git + Jira workflow in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, jira

I am an `Intellij Idea` user and I am very happy of the workflow I can have using together **Git** support and the **Jira connector**:

- Git support in Idea has the concept of change list, groups of related files you are modifying and that most likely you will commit all together.
- The Jira connector support creating change lists straight from Jira Issues, so that the change list has the name of the Jira issue.
- If you configure correctly Jira to access your Github repo, when you commit Jira will show you your commits under the issue.

Is it possible to reproduce the same workflow in *Visual Studio 2012*?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://www.atlassian.com/software/ide-connectors/overview ?

Comment: I did and I am using it. But there is no integration with Git, because there is no Git support bundled with Visual Studio (although there are good ones).

Comment: Visual Studio has git [integrated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850437.aspx). At least the most recent version.

Comment: correct. I am on Visual studio 2012, I corrected my question